# How to find html substring including tags in a html string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a string and substring , I would like to get the first index of substring in that string , i use `string.indexOf` for this purpose but when there are html tags it always return `-1` . I am working in CKEDITOR

Please suggest any method.

---

(from the comments)

i am talking about this thing `​str = "<html><head><body><p>hello</p><p>world</p><body> </head></​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​html>"; sub_str = "<p>hello</p><p>world</p>";` now `str.indexOf(sub_str)` will return -1

Comment: Post sample code please.

Comment: can you provide your code ???

Comment: startpoint = all_data.indexOf(selected_text);

Comment: all_data => whole html string
selected_text => html substring

Comment: Are you trying to NOT find matches inside HTML Tags?
smth Like   <body><p>my body is over the ocean</p></body>
myhtml.indexof("body");

Comment: Actually i am selecting text in ckeditor and then finding the index of that selected text in javascript

Comment: This is why you are asked for code (or a link). You haven't mentioned ckeditor in your question. It is relevant.

Comment: How are you retrieving the HTML from CKEDITOR as a string? Are you using selection.getSelectedText()?

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "<html><head><body><p>hello</p><p>world</p><body> </head></html>";
sub_str = "<p>hello</p><p>world</p>";

alert(str.indexOf(sub_str));
```

see this code here http://jsfiddle.net/wQSbe/7/
use sub_str without quotes in indexof(), if we use with quotes it will return -1, why because it searches for a string which maches 'sub_str'. It doesn't find in the given string. So It returns -1

Comment: Actually i am selecting html in ckeditor and when i try to find the index of that selected html it gives me its wrong position when there are more then one html tags

Comment: @AbubakarShams previously you didn't mention ckeditor in your question, I don't have knowledge about ckeditor. I hope the above code works.